# How can you control the pagination URL?

Tags: pagination, config

How can you control the pagination URL and change this:

```
http://example.com/blog/P#
```

to this:

```
http://example.com/blog/page-#
```

? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into the EE core that would allow you to do this.

You have a few options though. The easiest would be to use something like [Better Pagination](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/better-pagination) which will allow you to setup different Pagination URLS.

The other option is to build the url you want and use some template logic to grab the correct URL.